# Connecting and Disconnecting sockets in android

Tags: android, sockets

iam doing a small chat app in android with socket .. I want the app in such a way that the  socket should  connect when we open the app and it should disconnect as soon as the user leaves the app..and the main thing is, it should be connected when user is at any activity in the app(example :profile, create groups or any activity other than conversation page) Like same thing in whatsapp and similar chat app..How this can be achieved?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My trick, and I'm sure there are others, is to create an **abstract BaseActivity with an activity counter** and have all 'real' activities instantiate from this class:

```
abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {

   protected static int numForegroundActivities;


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        numForegroundActivities++; // no need for thread sync
   }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (--numForegroundActivities == 0) {
            doAppClosedCode(); // <----------------------------
        }
    }    
}




// all instantiable activities should extends BaseActivity
class MainActivity extends BaseActivity ....
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It is a bit better to do this with ActivityLifecycleCallbacks (see my answer) since you don't have to have all your activity extend a base class.

Comment: You are right, if BaseActivity were to be used only for activity counting purpose. In most non-trivial projects that is not the case. I find myself using it for more common UI logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor when Activities are in the foreground by using this api:

[Application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks%28android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks%29)

An Activity is in the foreground when onActivityStarted is called.